# Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to update each product individually, where multiple products can be located in one order. When I press submit/update, I am sending the orderid to the controller alongside the new product quantity. This is the error I am shown:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: New transaction is not allowed
>   because there are other threads running in the session.

This is the controller which redirects to the form.

```
[HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "ADM")]
    public ActionResult UpdateDetails(Guid id)
    {
        BusinessLayer.Orders blorder = new BusinessLayer.Orders();
        return View(blorder.GetOrderDetailsByOrderId(id));
    }
```

This is the form.

```
@model IQueryable<CommonLayer.ORDERDETAIL>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UpdateDetails";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>UpdateDetails</h2>


<table class="table table-striped" style="font-size:medium;">
    <tr>

        <th>
            Order Details ID
        </th>
        <th>
            Price
        </th>
        <th>
            VAT Rate
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantity
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderDetailsId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductPrice)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductVATRate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form action="/order/updatedetails/@item.OrderDetailsId" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="text" name="prodqty" value="@item.ProductQuantity" />
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                <br />
                                <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

</table>
```

This is the controller which the form redirects to.

```
[HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "ADM")]
    public ActionResult UpdateDetails(Guid id, int prodqty)
    {
        BusinessLayer.Orders blorder = new BusinessLayer.Orders();
        CommonLayer.ORDERDETAIL orderdetail = blorder.GetOrderDetailByDetailId(id);
        blorder.UpdateOrderDetails(orderdetail, prodqty);
        return RedirectToAction("ViewOrder");
    }
```

This is the code used for the actual update of the stock.

```
public void UpdateOrderDetails(CommonLayer.ORDERDETAIL orderdetail, int prodqty)
    {
            CommonLayer.ORDERDETAIL orderDetails = this.GetOrderDetail(orderdetail.OrderDetailsOrderId);
            CommonLayer.ORDERDETAIL od = new CommonLayer.ORDERDETAIL();
            DataLayer.DAProducts daprod = new DataLayer.DAProducts(this.Entities);
            CommonLayer.PRODUCT product = daprod.GetProduct(orderDetails.OrderDetailsProductId);

            od.OrderDetailsProductId = orderDetails.OrderDetailsProductId;
            od.OrderDetailsId = orderDetails.OrderDetailsId;
            od.OrderDetailsOrderId = orderDetails.OrderDetailsOrderId;
            od.ProductVATRate = orderDetails.ProductVATRate;
            od.ProductPrice = orderDetails.ProductPrice;
            od.ProductQuantity = prodqty;
            if (od.ProductQuantity <= product.ProductQuantity)
            {
                if (od.ProductQuantity > orderDetails.ProductQuantity)
                {
                    product.ProductQuantity -= (od.ProductQuantity - orderDetails.ProductQuantity);
                    daprod.UpdateProduct(product);
                    this.Entities.Entry(orderDetails).CurrentValues.SetValues(od);
                    this.Entities.SaveChanges();
                }
                else if (od.ProductQuantity < orderDetails.ProductQuantity)
                {
                    product.ProductQuantity += (orderDetails.ProductQuantity - od.ProductQuantity);
                    daprod.UpdateProduct(product);
                    this.Entities.Entry(orderDetails).CurrentValues.SetValues(od);
                    this.Entities.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Stock is too low");
        }
    }
```

And this is where the error is shown, on `this.Entities.SaveChanges();`

```
public void UpdateProduct(CommonLayer.PRODUCT product)
    {
        CommonLayer.PRODUCT ExistingProduct = this.GetProduct(product.ProductId);
        this.Entities.Entry(ExistingProduct).CurrentValues.SetValues(product);
        this.Entities.SaveChanges();
    }
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: can your save changes get executed 2 times (if and else if) in UpdateOrderDetails method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohhhh. I think you are re-using your Entities wayyyy too much. Try initializing a new context for each transaction you use... Do this (Again, remove the `SaveChanges` from the `UpdateProduct` function so that you will only call `SaveChanges` once...Try this before your `if-else-if` block

```
using(var context = new CommonLayer.DBModelEntities()){
 if (od.ProductQuantity > orderDetails.ProductQuantity)
 {
   product.ProductQuantity -= (od.ProductQuantity - orderDetails.ProductQuantity);
   daprod.UpdateProduct(product, context);
   context.Entry(orderDetails).CurrentValues.SetValues(od);
 }
 else if (od.ProductQuantity < orderDetails.ProductQuantity)
 {
    product.ProductQuantity += (orderDetails.ProductQuantity - od.ProductQuantity);
    daprod.UpdateProduct(product, context);
    context.Entry(orderDetails).CurrentValues.SetValues(od);
 }

 context.SaveChanges();
}
```

With this, you should also change the `UpdateProduct` function to receive the current database context you are using

```
public void UpdateProduct(CommonLayer.PRODUCT product, CommonLayer.DBModelEntities context)
{
  CommonLayer.PRODUCT ExistingProduct = this.GetProduct(product.ProductId);
  context.Entry(ExistingProduct).CurrentValues.SetValues(product);
}
```

Comment: I removed the SaveChanges(), still didn't work :( I cannot seem to get it to work in any way...

Comment: Ok, ok, let's try another way... Do an experiment and remove ALL SaveChanges() from your code... try and see if it still has any errors... Just so you can really narrow it down to SaveChanges() being your culprit

Comment: without SaveChanges(), no errors show up, so I guess that's the problem :s

Comment: See modified answer now

Comment: This code doesn't show any errors whatsoever, but nothing is updated, neither the order nor the stock :/

Comment: Oops, my bad. context should also be used for the entities entry. See modified answer

Comment: Good! Try to get into the habit of making your database contexts short-lived by using the `using` function... Or if you want, you can study up more on Transactions and try to implement what I did in the first answer. Just keep on experimenting! :)

Comment: Will do buddy! :) Thank you for your time :D

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to put in your begin, save/rollback transactions within the controller as to avoid multiple instances of `SaveChanges` calls which was what you did in your core functions `UpdateProduct` and `UpdateOrderDetails`.. which triggered the thread exception

Try this, remove all existing `SaveChanges` call on your core functions `UpdateProduct` and `UpdateOrderDetails` and put them in your controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "ADM")]
public ActionResult UpdateDetails(Guid id, int prodqty)
{
  // Entities.BeginTransaction here;
  BusinessLayer.Orders blorder = new BusinessLayer.Orders();
  CommonLayer.ORDERDETAIL orderdetail = blorder.GetOrderDetailByDetailId(id);
  blorder.UpdateOrderDetails(orderdetail, prodqty);

  /*Now, check if your data can be Saved by triggering SaveChanges()
   if(Entities.SaveChanges)
  {
    Entities.Commit
  }else
  {
    Entities.Rollback
  } */

  return RedirectToAction("ViewOrder");
}
```

Here you can see that you can detect if the record is saved properly, in which case you can commit it to the database, else you can simply rollback the transaction

All those snippets as comments can be varied depending on how you declare your entities, but this should help solve your problem while following good practice in using Transactions in MVC

Comment: I'm still a student and kind of a beginner when it comes to mvc, is it possible if you could clarify exactly what I need to do? I am not familiar with using entities within my controller. I named my database model as DBModelEntities, if that helps. Would really appreciate your help as I'm really frustrated at the moment :(

Comment: Okay, do you have access to your DBModelEntities in your controller? If not then you need to declare and initialize it first in the controller so that you can perform db transactions in controller

Comment: Thanks alot! ok that is done, but when I enter Entities. , BeginTransaction is not available. 

CommonLayer.DBModelEntities Entities = new CommonLayer.DBModelEntities();

Comment: Try to access the Database class of your Entities variable, like this: `DBModelEntities.Database.BeginTransaction`

Comment: Doesn't allow me to do it like that, get an error under the Database keyword

Comment: Hmmm.. okay, maybe you do not have the proper initializations yet... Okay.. I'm gonna post another answer which is easier to do, but not in good practice... I'll keep this answer here just so you can get back to it in the future if ever you want to keep track of it

Comment: You're brilliant mate! Thanks alot!!

Comment: Take a look at the new answer

Comment: Aren't you giving direct access to your data access layer in the presentation layer with this? (prefer your other answer which I've upvoted)